# Dependency injection with utility classes

Tags: ember.js, dependency-injection

In EmberJS, if I have a utility class I've injected into the container via an initializer, how can I inject dependencies into that utility class?

For example, one could inject a messages class with this initializer:

```
import Messages from 'app/utils/messages';

var injectMessagesInitializer = {
    name: 'injectMessages',
    before: 'authentication',

    initialize: function (container, application) {
        application.register('messages:main', Messages, {initialize: false, singleton: true});

        application.inject('controller', 'messages', 'messages:main');
        application.inject('component', 'messages', 'messages:main');
        application.inject('router', 'messages', 'messages:main');
        application.inject('route', 'messages', 'messages:main');
    }
};

export default injectMessagesInitializer;
```

Now, I'd like to be able to inject a Notifier class into that Messages utility. Can I do something like the following?

```
import Notifier from 'notifier';

var injectNotifierIntoMessagesInitializer = {
    name: 'injectNotifierIntoMessages',
    after: 'injectMessages',

    initialize: function (container, application) {    
        application.inject('messages', 'notifier', 'notifier:main');
    }
};

export default injectNotifierIntoMessagesInitializer;
```

Inside the utility class:

```
var Messages = Ember.Object.extend({
    showError: function (message, options) {
        this.notifier.error(message, options);
    },
    showErrors: function (errors, options) {
        options = options || {};

        for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i += 1) {
           this.showError(errors[i].message || errors[i], options);
        }
    },
    ...
});
```

A couple things of note:

1. The notifier class is a simple notifier, something like [ember-cli-growl](https://github.com/ngenworks/ember-cli-growl) that does one thing well, throws single notifications.
2. The messages class is a wrapper for the notifier, adding convenience methods like showError, showErrors, showInfo, showWarn. Essentially, it abstracts the throwing of notifications so we can pivot to a different type or class of notifications in the future.